# NSURLConnection http status 400 , error (null)

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to post the data on the server which ask for Json format. here's the requirement of json format that needs to be send to the server

```
{"storeId":"abc@gmail.com",
 "handleName":"abcd",
"profilePic":"(encoded bse64image in string)"
}
```

and response I will get is in json format

Here's what i am doing

```
- (void)postTo:(NSString *)urlString params:(NSDictionary *)params completion:(void (^)(id, NSError *))completion {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
    if (params.count) {
        NSMutableArray *paramArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *key in [params allKeys]) {
            NSString *encodedKey = [key stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *encodedValue = [params[key] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *encodedPair = [[encodedKey stringByAppendingString:@"="] stringByAppendingString:encodedValue];
            [paramArray addObject:encodedPair];
        }        
        NSString *paramString = [paramArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];        
        NSData *data = [paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {        
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;      
        if (!error && httpResponse.statusCode < 400) {
            NSError *parseError;
            id parse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
            if (!parseError) {
                completion(parse, nil);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"parse error %@", parseError);
                completion(nil, parseError);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"http status %d, error %@", httpResponse.statusCode, error);
            completion(nil, error);
        }
  }];
```

and calling it like this

```
 NSString *storeId=@"abc@gmail.com";
            NSString *handleName = @"abc";
           // NSString *profilePic=@"samplestringtest";
        UIImageView *image= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpg"] ];
        _profilepicImageView.image= image.image;
        NSData *imag64 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profilepicImageView.image, 0.5f);
        NSString *encoded = [imag64 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
       NSString *urlString = @"http://server.cloud.com/user/registration";
       NSDictionary *params = @{@"storeId":storeId,
                               @"handleName":handleName,
                               @"profilePic":encoded
                                };
       [self postTo:urlString params:params completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && result != nil) {
              
                NSLog(@"%@", result);
                HUD.progress = 1.0f;
                [HUD hide:YES];
                [self afterSignupProceed];
                } else {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
```

I am getting http status 400 , error null

Comment: I see nothing RestKit or AFNetworking code in your question. A 400 error means your requested URL path doesn't exist, have you verified it?

Comment: @Wain : may i get your emailID.. I am so stuck at this point ..yesterday I tried restkit and now basic ..but I am not sure whats happening ..It would be great If we can chat

Comment: @Wain : is there any simpler way to check if the url exist ?

Comment: Paste the URL into a browser, you might get an error, but it shouldn't be a 400

Comment: @Wain : It's coming blank screen and no errors..

Comment: Log the response, and error, and data. Check server logs. Switch to the `NSURLConnection` delegate approach so you can check for redirections / auth issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is hard to answer with the information you have given. But I can see the following that might help you.

Firstly, a `400` response code is a server code. It does mean that there was no connection error, so it is expected that the `NSError` value is `nil`. `400` is the value for `Bad Request`, so it is likely that the server dislikes what you have sent. E.g. a parameter is missing.

Secondly, you seem to be sending the data html-form encoded and then telling the server that it is json-encoded. This could be the source of the `400` error from the server. Maybe it only supports json, and the data you sent is not correct json.

Without further information about the format the server is expecting I cannot help you more.

Comment: bascially ,this is user registration where I have to send data in json format to the server where first willbe emailid,username and profilePic with enconded in base64 and server will return me in the json format ..so how should i go about it ?

Comment: What additional information I should give so that you can help me out ?